# Linker error with GLFW on OS 10.10

Tags: opengl, glfw

I'm trying to compile the following

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    return 0;
}
```

just to verify that my GLFW installation is working. I use the terminal with

```
clang++ -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -I/opt/local/include/ test.c
```

but I receive a linker error for the glfwInit function:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      _main in test-d8c21e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I have installed glfw with `sudo port install glfw` and followed every possible tutorial I've found. I can verify that the `libglfw.dylib` file can be found at `/opt/local/lib/` as (I think) it should.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link with GLFW[3] as well, e.g., add:
`-L/opt/local/lib -lglfw3`

If you have the `pkgconfig` port installed, you can also take advantage of that with:

```
clang `pkg-config glfw3 --cflags` test.c -o test \
`pkg-config glfw3 --static --libs`
```

You may not need the `--static` flag if you have: `libglfw3.dylib`, as opposed to using: `libglfw3.a`, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Ah I thought I tried that, but I used -I/opt/local/lib instead of -L. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xcode, you must add the libglfw3.a library when linking binaries.

Heres the trick

1. Show hidden folders. Paste this into terminal: defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
2. Relaunch a finder window and navigate to Macintosh HD\usr
3. Drag the usr folder to the "Favorites" side in the terminal
4. In xcode, click the add "+" to link binaries, then click "Add Other"
5. navigate to the libglfw3.a and add it!

If it still does not work, here are some instructions that helped me.

https://engineering-game-dev.com/2013/08/14/glfw-compiling-source-and-creating-an-xcode-project/comment-page-1/#comment-1400